# What is "package manager cache" (pacman, apt)?

Tags: apt, package-management, pacman

I have several questions about Linux package managers:

- What exactly is "package manager cache"?
- Should I keep it or is it safe to clean it up completely?
- What can go wrong if the cache is cleared completely?
- If I clear cache, will my packages automatically update?
- What type of data is stored in this cache?

Context:

- "pacman" from Arch linux
- "apt" from Debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will focus on `apt`, but the principles apply to package managers in general.

Package managers keep track of different pieces of information; notably

- details of the packages installed on the system
- details of the packages available in repositories
- potentially, archives of packages

In addition to that, they may also maintain different forms of that information, or results of calculations made on the information (*e.g.* dependency trees), and use those in order to speed up operations.

In `apt`’s case, the `apt` cache (as manipulated by `apt-cache`) is the latter: an optimised representation of the package information available to `apt`. It lives in `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` and its statistics can be seen with

```
apt-cache stats
```

Removing it will cause it to be re-created the next time it’s needed, without any adverse effects other than the delay incurred.

In addition to that, `apt` maintains a package cache in `/var/cache/apt/archives`; this is what is cleaned up by `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean`. Any files removed from this cache will also be retrieved (if possible) the next time they are needed, again without adverse effects other than the delay required to obtain them, the necessity to be online to retrieve them, and the possibility that the files may no longer be available.

Details of the packages available in repositories aren’t listed as a cache but they technically are, since they can also be downloaded if they are deleted; this is what `apt-get update` does. By default in `apt`, this information is stored in files under `/var/lib/apt` — note the use of `/var/lib` rather than `/var/cache`. Note that these files will *not* be retrieved automatically if they are removed.

The only data essential to the system, and which can’t easily be re-created, is the information on packages installed in the system. In `apt`-based systems, this is managed by `dpkg` and lives in `/var/lib/dpkg`.

On `apt`-based systems, package updates rely on information retrieved by `apt-get update`; if that is run periodically, any missing caches will be populated, and any other operation depending on the cached data will proceed (including package upgrades, in whatever way they are applied).